# After refresh setTimeout will work or Not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have script like below. 
if i refresh a page before (3 Minutes)`setTimeout`, get_details function call will work or not?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    get_details(user);
}, 18000);
```

Comment: Yes it will work, after 3 mins of page reload

Comment: @Satpal Thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you refresh while the timer is running it will start all over again when the page reloads.

So to answer your question, yes the `get_details()` function will be called after the refresh but only after the full 3 minutes has elapsed since the refresh occurred.

Comment: @Raj_King: if you have found the answer to your question, then can you close this question.

Answer (score 4):

It depends when you invoke the setTimeout:

- setTimeout invoked on dom ready - Yes, get_details() will run after 180 sec
- setTimout invoked on event (e.g. button click) - Button was clicked --> setTimeout has been invoked --> page was refreshed, the queue of the event loop was cleared and get_details will not be invoked.